# Is there ever a need to have GET request API as POST is better in every way?

Tags: node.js, apache, rest, soap

So we were starting a new project from scratch and one of the developers suggested why have any GET API requests as POST API's are better in every which way. (At least when using a mobile client)

On further looking into this it does seem POST can do everything GET can do and it can do it better -

- slightly more secure as parameters are not in URL
- larger limit than GET request

So is there even a single reason to have a GET API ? (This will only be used from a mobile client so browser specific cacheing doesn't affect us)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there ever a need to have GET request API as POST is better in every way?

In general, yes.  In your specific circumstances -- maybe no.

`GET` and `POST` are [method tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.1).

> The request method token is the primary source of request semantics

They are a form of meta data included in the http request so that general purpose components can be aware of the request semantics and contribute constructively.

[POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) is, in a sense, the wildcard method - it can mean [anything](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).  But one of the consequences of this is - because the method has unconstrained semantics, general purpose components can't do anything useful other than pass the request along.

[GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1), however, has [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) semantics (which includes [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) semantics).  Because the request is idempotent, general purpose components know that they can resend a GET request when the server returns no response (ie messages being lost on unreliable transport); general purpose components can know that representations of the resource can be pre-fetched, reducing perceived latency.

You dismissed caching as a concern earlier, but you may want to rethink that - the [cache constraint](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4) is an important element that helped the web take over the world.

Reducing everything to POST reduces HTTP from an [application for transferring documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) to dumb transport.

Using HTTP for transport isn't necessarily wrong: Simple Object Access Protocol ([SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)) works that way, as does [gRPC](https://grpc.io/).  You still get authorization, and conditional requests; features of HTTP that you might otherwise need to roll your own.

You aren't doing REST at that point, but that's OK; not everybody has to.

> That doesn’t mean that I think everyone should design their own systems according to the REST architectural style. REST is intended for long-lived network-based applications that span multiple organizations. If you don’t see a need for the constraints, then don’t use them. ([Fielding, 2008](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-742))